# Is there any meaning to "I'm drowning in footwear!"?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, spike

A dreaming Spike issues the line, "I'm drowning in footwear!" in the series finale of *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*. My question is: does this line or Spike's dream have any deep meaning (like foreshadowing a future event or referencing to something that happened in the past)  or is it just a silly one-liner?

On the one hand, dreams in *Buffy* are often prophetic and vague lines spoken in dreams often foreshadow future events (see dreams foreshadowing Dawn's arrival). On the other hand, there's the cheese guy.

I've done some poking around on the internet and found a shaky claim that this line is referencing the Shanshu (phonetically similar to "sans shoe") prophecy but this claim provided no source and it seemed like a fan theory more than anything else.

Mr. Whedon comments on the silliness of this line during the episode's commentary, but, at least in my mind, doesn't claim that it is *just* a silly line.

Comment: If you've watched the commentary and noted that it's not referenced as a prophetic line, I sincerely doubt you're going to get anything else.

Comment: I was hoping there might be something I missed in the comics or maybe someone asked one of the writers this question in an interview. But if you feel this question is not worth asking, I can certainly delete it.

Comment: I'd leave it up. I'm interested to see if there's an answer out there. You might, though, want to try reaching out to some of those involved in the writing/production to see if you can generate an answer that way.

Comment: Can't we just forget s7?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the James Marsters Database it was (interpretation) a throwaway line from Whedon that he would just drop in for the actors from time to time, quote James:

[James Marsters db](https://jamesdb.com/index.php)

> "I'm drowning in footwear, yeah. Usually when Joss gives a line like that which is really funny and over the top, other actors kinda chafe from it, don't wanna like, embarrass themselves - me, I go for it so much. And like, Joss, the first take, he blew it, he laughed at the monitors, he blew the sound. And he's like, ok that was fabulous, let's film, just bring it down a little. Never afraid to make a fool of myself, you know."

Comment: Nice find. You have my +1